# Error installing grunt-contrib-jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, grunt-contrib-jasmine

When I try to install it with this command:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-jasmine --save-dev
```

... I get an error:

> npm WARN package.json grunt-contrib-connect@0.3.0 No README data
>
> npm WARN package.json karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.7 No README data
>
> npm WARN package.json karma-firefox-launcher@0.1.4 No README data
>
> npm WARN package.json karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 No README data
>
> npm WARN package.json http-proxy@1.0.0 No repository field.
>
> npm WARN package.json uglify-js@2.2.5 'repositories' (plural) Not supported. > Please pick one as the 'repository' field/phantomjs@1.9.17 install C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website\node_modules\grunt-contr
>   ib-jasmine\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs
>
> node install.js
>
> Download already available at C:\Users\GARRAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip
>
> Extracting zip contents
>
> Removing > C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jasmine\node_mo
>   dules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom
>
> Copying extracted folder C:\Users\GARRAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip-extrac
>   t-1433927117004\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows -> C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website\node_mod
>   ules\grunt-contrib-jasmine\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom
>
> Writing location.js file
>
> Done. Phantomjs binary available at C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website\node_modules\gr
>   unt-contrib-jasmine\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom\phantomjs.exe
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\
>
> npm-cli.js" "install" "grunt-contrib-jasmine" "--save-dev"
>
> npm ERR! node v0.12.0
>
> npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
>
> npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
>
> npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt-contrib-jasmine does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies req
>   uirements!
>
> npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs@0.1.10 wants grunt-contrib-jasmine@~0.5.3
>
> npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul@0.2.6 wants grunt-contrib-jasmine@>=0.3.1
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website\npm-debug.log

How can I fix this error?